# How to separate two DC voltages in a dual power supply?

Tags: power-supply, audio, raspberry-pi, noise, induction

I have a dual power supply (Lacie ACLG-51) that supplies both 12V DC and 5V DC with a common neutral (3 wires)
I have used it to drive a little system composed of a Raspberry Pi (5V), USB HUB (5V), TFT (12V) and audio amplifier (12V) The power of the Lacie is enough for all the equipment.

The problem that I have is that I get a huge induced noise in the audio amplifier (it is unusable). If I use a stand-alone 5V to drive the Raspberry Pi I get no noise induced. It seems to be caused by using the same reference driving the audio source (RasPi) and audio amplifier, or so I have read.

How could I get two different supply voltages (5DC + common and 12DC + common) so they don't share the same common, using the Lacie power supply?

I hope I made myself clear, sorry if it is confusing!

Comment: It might also be ground loops in your wiring. A block diagram showing how the wires interconnect might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to isolate your power, is an isolated DC/DC converter.
These are pricey, and in effect usually you're better of having two power supplies.

What you could try, however, is isolating your audio signal. This is something the amplifier should do for you, it pulls the audio up to its internal virtual ground, which may well differ from the raspberry's virtual ground.
Or at least, it should do this.
The virtual ground is needed, because audio signals normally go from +V to -V around the ground of the same cable, where V is the voltage of the medium. Can be 100mV, 1V or more, depending. 1Vp-p is quite common for audio stereo jacks (V = 0.5V).

If your Raspy generates 2.5V on the ground ring to refer the audio to, and your amplifier just accepts the ground it gets and tries to link that to half its power (6Vdc) stuff happens... Probably mainly on the raspy's side, because they share the same 0V reference.

What you can try, just as an experiment, is the following:

Connect a 10uF, 16V bipolar capacitor or higher values between RasPi's Right and Audio Amp's Right.
Connect another one of the same values between RasPi's Left and Audio Amp's Left.
Connect another one of the same values between RasPi's Ground and Audio Amp's Ground.
Now add a 10k resistor from Audio Amp's Right to Audio Amp's Ground.
Add another 10k resistor from Audio Amp's Left to Audio Amp's Ground.

Now, this trick may give low-frequency suppression if the audio amp's inputs are lower than 10k input impedance and quite possibly you won't need the extra resistors, but it's better to start with them.
If you experience too much damping in low frequencies you can increase the caps and the resistor values.

This is just an experiment, but it may well be "a" solution. The capacitors are basically frequency dependant resistors. They don't conduct any DC current, but they conduct the audio signal and they conduct better and better the higher the frequency.

---

Edit: I fount the Circuit Lab button! Replaced the text art with a Circuit Lab drawing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f64jTw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C1 = C2 = C3 = 10uF, 16V, ceramic/other bipolar. To make sure the capacitors operate safely and predictably it's best to make them at least rated for the maximum voltage in the system, i.e. 12V.
Resistors may be optional, depending on the Amp.

Comment: Your text differs from the schematic. In the text you say “Now add a 10k resistor from Audio Amp's Right to Audio Amp's Ground. Add another 10k resistor from Audio Amp's Left to Audio Amp's Ground.”, so Rs from channel to ground, none from channel to channel (which doesn’t make any sense to me, either)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Silly mistake. The text art had the ground in the middle for convenience, this may have driven some of the confusion. Or I should just stay away while I should be working. Going to fix it right away. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care too much about the audio quality you could isolate the audio with a transformer as sometimes used in car stereos, which would probably make the noise go away.

You could also get an isolated DC-DC converter to do exactly what you asked, but it might actually be cheaper to get a second Lacie ACLG-51!

An example of DC-DC converter, for up to 10W, would be this [series](http://www.us.tdk-lambda.com/ftp/specs/CC10-xF-E_spc_en.pdf). You can get a 5V:5V type or a 12V:5V etc. You can do a parametric search at a distributor to pick the best part for your job.

It's not impossible that it would be feasible to crack open the case and separate the two supplies, as they often use two isolated transformer secondaries (sometimes they are in series for the higher voltage though), but I would not suggest that for safety reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Something that you can try is as follows: Connect the audio signals from the Pi to the amplifier as normal.  Make the audio ground wire from the Pi to the amp as short and heavy (thick) as you can.  Then connect only the +5V from the Pi to the power supply and see what happens.

What you need to do is to look at the current path.  If you have separate ground wires from the Pi and amp that meet at the power supply, current changes on the Pi ground wire will couple noise into the audio ground path to the amp.

By treating the audio input ground of the amp as your star ground point, you might reduce the noise to the point where it doesn't bother you.

This may or may not work but it doesn't cost anything to try.

If this doesn't give you enough of an improvement, your two options are to either use an isolated DC-DC converter to power the Pi *or* isolate your audio path.  I normally use really good audio transformers for this (my company sells inexpensive but *very* good audio transformers) but you could also use a pair of diff-amp chips.

I used to use the Analog Devices SSM2141 chips (1 chip per channel) but now use the newer / better chips from THAT Corporation.  The only downside to those chips is that you have to go through a few hoops to make them operate from your single 12V supply.